# how do you initialize the confidence score for r-cnn (Region-Convolutional Neural Network)

Tags: conv-neural-network, tensorflow, object-detection

I follow the arguments for training an r-cnn to derive the bounding box and confidence score.

https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2014/papers/Erhan_Scalable_Object_Detection_2014_CVPR_paper.pdf

What I have trouble is how to do the first step of arg min F(x,l,c) eqn 4 when c is not yet known. 
here x_ij is the coefficient linking proposed box i to true box j
l is the location coordinates for that box
c is the confidence score for that box

I know that the initial l can be just whatever was in the proposed region set. It will get adjusted later, but what is the c_i values when performing this arg min_x?

Comment: Can you edit this question to explain what your acronyms, functions, and variables refer to?